# Proving a function is in $L^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

> Let $f:\Bbb{R^2}\to\Bbb{R}$ be a lebesgue measurable function, $f\in L^{\infty}$. For every $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$, define $g_\theta(x)=f(x\cos(\theta),x\sin(\theta))$. Prove that for almost every $\theta$, $g_\theta\in L^{\infty}$.

So, first I make a claim that $g_\theta$ is measurable - this is because it is the composition of a continuous function (which is Lebesgue measurable) and a Lebesgue measurable function and therefore Lebesgue measurable. I wasn't able to solve the second part.
I thought maybe since $f$ is bounded a.e, then also $g_\theta$ must be bounded a.e, but I wasn't able to prove it.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Your definition of $g_\theta$ doesn't depend on $f$! You left something out.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Edited, thanks

Comment: This is analogous to Fubini's  theorem. If $f \in L^\infty$ and $L_y(x) = f(x,y)$, then $f_y \in L^\infty$ for almost every $y$. In your case instead of horizontal lines you are showing that $f$ is bounded on almost every line through the origin, parameterized by the angle $\theta$. Can you apply (or mimic the proof of) Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I believe fubini's theorem states that about functions in $L^1$ no?

Comment: If $f \in L^\infty$ there is $M$ with the property that the set $\{|f| > M\}$ has two dimensional measure zero. Fubini's theorem states (in part) that this set has one dimensional measure zero on almost every horizontal line, and $f$ is essentially bounded on those lines.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I think I get the idea, can you post it as an answer with a bit more details?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the "polar coordinates" mapping $P: \mathbb{R}^2 \to (-\infty, \infty)\times [0,2\pi)$ is measurable, invertible with measurable inverse, and continuous almost everywhere. Moreover, let $\mu_2$ denote standard Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\mu_P$ denote standard Lebesgue measure on the product space $(-\infty, \infty)\times [0,2\pi)$. Then the measures $\mu_2$ and $\mu_P\circ P$ defined by $\mu_P\circ P(A) = \mu_P(P(A))$ are mutually absolutely continuous, that is $\mu_2(A) = 0$ if and only if $\mu_P \circ P(A) =0$ (why?).

The function $g:(-\infty, \infty)\times [0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by  $g(x,\theta) = f(xcos(\theta),xsin(\theta))=f(P^{-1}(x,\theta))$ is measurable, and further is an element of $L^\infty$, since for any $M > \|f\|_\infty$, $\mu_P( |g| > M) = \mu_P( |f \circ P^{-1}| > M ) = 0$, since $\mu_2(\{|f| > M \})=0$ (why?).

Now it follows by Fubini's theorem that the sections  $g_\theta$ of $g$ must be in $L^\infty$ for almost all $\theta$. In particular by applying Fubini's theorem we have that
$$0 = \mu_P( |g| > M) =  \int_{(-\infty, \infty)\times [0,2\pi)} 1_{\{|g|>M\}}d\mu_P = \int_{[0,2\pi)}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{\{|g_\theta|>M\}} d\mu_1\right)d\mu([0,2\pi))$$,
hence $\mu\{|g_\theta|>M\} =0$ for almost all $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, which gives what we need.